# One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head

Tags: html, css, jsf

I write the following facelet `index.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:myCC="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/hui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <head>

        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/centering.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="centerClass">
            <mycc:logpass/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i'm getting content of this facelet from browser i have

```
One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.
```

And so html from console is following:

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>

</head>
```

But if i write

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:mycc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/hui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <link href="css/centering" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="centerClass">
            <mycc:logpass/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

there is no this error message. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<h:head>` instead of `<head>`

`<head>` tag is just a html tag and it has no place in JSF component tree.

`<h:head>` tag is a JSF tag. `<h:outputStylesheet>` is also a JSF tag which can be solvable inside `<h:head>` tag.

Furthermore, `<h:outputStylesheet>` has a counterpart `<link>` in html. `<h:outputStylesheet>` is designed to read static files from `WebContent/resources` directory. So you should put your css folter to this directory, then your style sheet will be read. If `<h:outputStylesheet>` is used, it is interpreted from JSF to a html tag, which browsers can understand html tags as in the following format. Pay attention to `/ProjectRoot/javax.faces.resource` prefix.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ProjectRoot/javax.faces.resource/css/centering.css.xhtml" />
```

Standart html tags can also be used inside JSF tags. That's why you do not see any problem with html tags.